# Why multiple $x$ of $y = xe^{αx}$ when deduction the solution of constant coefficient differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I read this in the book called *The calculus Lifesaver*. In the chapter of Constant coefficient differential equation, the author writes how to deduce the expression of the solution in different situation. When there is two different solid root, the solution is supposed as $y = e^{αx}$, when you substitute this into differential equation, you can get the expression. Then why when there is a double root, the solution is supposed as $y = x e^{αx}$? Why multiple an $x$ to it?

I got lost when I tried to search for the answer because I'm quite not familiar with mathematic terms in English. So if there's any answer or website or textbook that already explained this question, please let me know! Thank you guys.

Comment: The short answer: we need to ensure a linearly independent set of solutions. I forget the whole reasoning, though.

Comment: Why is that not linearly independent set of solutions without the x?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a double root of the characteristic polynomial, then $y_1=e^{\alpha x}$ is one known solution to your DE. The standard approach to acquire another independent solution $y_2$ is to assume $y_2$ takes the form $y_2=ve^{\alpha x}$ for some unknown function $v$. Plug this expression for $y_2$ into your DE and solve for $v_2$.

Comment: The fact that it's linearly independent after you put in the $x$ is not that hard to see; you can prove it by looking at the Wronskian, but you can intuitively see that it will work at least when the roots aren't pure imaginary by thinking about small $x$ and large $x$. The non-obvious thing is that $x e^{\lambda x}$ is a solution at all.

Comment: Thanks guys! I now realized the real question is that why you should find a linearly independent solution for $y$ when there is a double root. I guess that has something to do with the deduce of general solution $y = Ae^{kx}$?

Comment: I have a new thought. Is that because we already knew that the solution is $y = Ae^{x} + Bxe^{x}$, so only when we suppose $y = xe^{x}$ and substitute it in $ay^{''}+by^{'}+cy$, can we get $ay^{''}+by^{'}+cy = (a^2+b+c)xe^{x}+(2a+b)e^{x}$ which is $y = Ae^{x} + Bxe^{x}$？

Answer (score 1):

Take an example:
$$y''-2y'+y=0$$
You get only a single solution since:
$$r^2-2r+1=(r-1)^2=0 \implies r=1$$
$$\implies y=e^x$$
Note that the DE can be rewritten as:
$$y''-2y'+y=0$$
$$(y'-y)'-(y'-y)=0$$
$$e^{-x}(y'-y)'-e^{-x}(y'-y)=0$$
$$(e^{-x}(y'-y))'=0$$
$$(ye^{-x})''=0$$
Integrate twice:
$$ye^{-x}=c_1x+c_2$$
$$y=e^{x}(c_1x+c_2)$$
So the solutions are:
$e^x$ and $xe^x$

Comment: Thanks! That concisely shows how to deduce the form of the general solution.

Comment: You're welcome @dbadaLynn

Answer (score 0):

An approach to deriving this from scratch that I like is called operator factorization. Say you have $p(D)y=f$ where $p$ is a polynomial with leading coefficient $1$ and $D$ is the derivative operator. Say $p$ has degree $2$ for simplicity of notation.

You can factor $p$ to get $(D-\lambda_1)(D-\lambda_2)y = f$. Now you can remove each of these $D-\lambda_i$ operators one at a time, by solving for what's left over. So first you look at $(D-\lambda_1)y_1=f$ then you would have a particular solution given by $y_1=e^{\lambda_1 t} \int e^{-\lambda_1 s} f(s) ds$. At the next step you look for $(D-\lambda_2) y_2 = y_1$ so $y_2=e^{\lambda_2 t} \int e^{-\lambda_2 s} y_1(s) ds$. Now $y_2$ is a particular solution to the original equation.

If you had a higher order constant coefficient problem then you could continue. Also, note that in all these integrals, you can choose the constant of integration to be zero, since you're just looking for a particular solution. I will do this without comment below.

Now you can choose what order you want to factor in, so you can put whatever $\lambda$ appears on the right side as $\lambda_1$. Then you see that $y_1=e^{\lambda_1 t} \int e^{-\lambda_1 s} e^{\lambda_1 s} ds = t e^{\lambda_1 t}$.

Comment: Thanks! That explains how general solution of a double root situation come.